# Add a "Has External URL" tab in review

Tags: feature-request, review, hyperlinks

I find that everytime I've flagged something as spam (and it was deemed a valid flag), what helped me spot spam was:

1. Has a link in the post
2. The link in the post originates outside of SO

Additionally, about 1/3 of the cases I've found, the user who entered the post that I flagged, has a profile URL that points to the same domain as the potential spam post.

I would like to request a new tab in the review section, perhaps named "Has External URL".

**EDIT**

I am only referring to posts that are already added to the review list; I'm not advocating that any and all posts with an external URL now be placed under review.

Comment: Wouldn't posts that include a legitimate reference have an external URL? How do you distinguish between the two?

Comment: Yes, can have legit external URLs in posts and via the current manual review process, you can distinguish what is a good post or spammy post.

Comment: Would this be for all users or just mods/admins?  I can see it for the latter potentially, but not for everyone

Comment: My intention was that it would be for reviewers (be they a user/mod/admin), as another way of grouping posts to review.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see this as a useful tool that should be shown to the users; however, it would be beneficial if a blacklist of URLs was possibly maintained by the spam filter - if that is even possible or feasible.

Comment: If you see spam with the same URL in it multiple times, flag for moderator attention and mention that you've seen the same URL multiple times. We can then let the dev team know about it so they can improve the spam filters.